# Display loop over PHP/MySQL query in array

Tags: php, dolibarr

I'm learning `PHP` in order to develop some modules into my software `Dolibarr` and I would like to know How I can loop over my query result and display each row in my array.

This is my script :

```
/*
 * View
 */

$query = "SELECT u.lastname as nom, u.firstname as prenom, u.datelastlogin as lastlogin";
$query.= " FROM ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."user as u";
$query.= " ORDER BY lastlogin DESC LIMIT 2";

$resql = $db ->query($query);
$num = $db->fetch_row($resql);

print '<table class="noborder" width="100%">';
print '<tr class="liste_titre"><th colspan="2">'.$langs->trans("Affichage des 2 dernières connexions").'</th></tr>';
if (! empty($conf->user->enabled))
{
        $LastLogin = '<tr class="oddeven">';
        $LastLogin.= '<td><a href="index.php">'.$langs->trans("Utilisateur").'</a></td><td align="right">'.$num[0]." ".$num[1]." ".$num[2].'</td>';
        $LastLogin.= "</tr>";
}

print $LastLogin;
print '</table>';
```

[image]

Up to now, I return only the first row from my query. I have never programmed in PHP before and I would like to know How I can display each line from my query into my array ?

I have to change `fetch_row` to `fetch_array` ?

Or, maybe better, split my array in 3 columns (column name, column firstname, column datelastlogin)

Something like this :

[image]

I don't really understand how I can do that.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT :**

I edited my script :

```
$query = "SELECT u.lastname as nom, u.firstname as prenom, u.datelastlogin as lastlogin";
$query.= " FROM ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."user as u";
$query.= " ORDER BY lastlogin DESC LIMIT 2";

$resql = $db ->query($query);
//$num = $db->fetch_array($resql);
while($num = $resql->fetch_assoc())
{
    $nums[] = $num;
}

print '<table class="noborder" width="100%">';
print '<tr class="liste_titre"><th colspan="2">'.$langs->trans("Dernières connexions").'</th></tr>';
if (! empty($conf->user->enabled))
{
    foreach($nums as $num)
    {
        $LastLogin = '<tr class="oddeven">';
        $LastLogin.= '<td><a href="index.php">'.$num['nom'].'</a></td><td>'.$num['prenom'].'</td><td>'.$num['lastlogin'].'</td>';
        $LastLogin.= "</tr>";
    }
}
print $LastLogin;
print '</table>';
```

But the array is not well-displayed :

[image]

Comment: `while($num = $db->fetch_row($resql)) { /* output one table row with row data */ }`

Comment: @CBroe I edited my question ;)

Comment: Problem with the code now is of course that you overwrite `$LastLogin` in each loop iteration. Initialize it with an empty string before the loop, and inside append only. This is all so basic btw., that you should perhaps rather go read a proper book/tutorial on the issue.

Comment: It's not according to the same thing. Here I'm trying to display result from a query and loop over each row in my array. Sorry if it's very basic ... But I'm Python developer not PHP. So I'm beginning from few time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helloo again :)

First of all I have to say that your error has nothing to do with the fact that you're new to PHP - but I think you're missing some basics in programming, because phyton works the same way for this scenario.

Lets look at your code:

```
if (! empty($conf->user->enabled))
{
    foreach($nums as $num)
    {
        $LastLogin = '<tr class="oddeven">';
        $LastLogin.= '<td><a href="index.php">'.$num['nom'].'</a></td><td>'.$num['prenom'].'</td><td>'.$num['lastlogin'].'</td>';
        $LastLogin.= "</tr>";
    }
}
print $LastLogin;
```

The problem here is that you overwrite `$LastLogin` all the time. That would work the same way in phyton. So you actually have two choices:

1. Place the print inside the forloop.
2. Output the result directly inside the loop.

I won't do an example for `1` since its only placing `print $LastLogin` inside the foreach loop - you don't need an example for that.

What I'll show you here bellow is the Code how I would write it in your case:

```
$query = "SELECT u.lastname as nom, u.firstname as prenom, u.datelastlogin as lastlogin";
$query.= " FROM ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."user as u";
$query.= " ORDER BY lastlogin DESC LIMIT 2";

$resql = $db ->query($query);
//$num = $db->fetch_array($resql);

print '<table class="noborder" width="100%">';
print '<tr class="liste_titre"><th colspan="2">'.$langs->trans("Dernières connexions").'</th></tr>';

if (! empty($conf->user->enabled)) {

    while($num = $resql->fetch_assoc()) {
        print '<tr class="oddeven">';
        print '<td><a href="index.php">'.$num['nom'].'</a></td><td>'.$num['prenom'].'</td><td>'.$num['lastlogin'].'</td>';
        print '</tr>';
    }
}

print '</table>';
```

There's actually no need to save all your results into a var and append all the time to it. Simply print the results directly, there's nothing that hold you back. For sure we could alk now about separating logic & views - but in this case there's not really a need for it.

Hope it helped :)